# I'm deleting rows from gridview but all data in the table is deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I want to add and delete rows dynamically in Gridview. Adding is successful. When I delete the row, the row is deleted successfully. But the data entered in other rows is cleared.
I want to delete rows. I also want to prevent the deletion of previously entered data.

**Default.aspx**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 4">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="row-edit" HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Select" runat="server"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle CssClass="row-edit"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
        }
    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
    protected void Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int indis = Gridview1.SelectedIndex;
        GridViewRow satir = Gridview1.Rows[indis];
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow[] _row = dtCurrentTable.Select("RowNumber=" + satir.Cells[0].Text);
        foreach (DataRow row in _row)
        {
            row.Delete();
        }
        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
        Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Here's the problem
(It won't let me paste it as a flat image.)
[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKVH1.gif)

Comment: When you attempt to delete a record. What is the value of `satir.Cells[0].Text`? Some sample data would be useful.

Comment: satir.Cells[0].Text = Row Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we are deleting one row at a time, right?

Ok, based on feedback, need/want this for the markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column2") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 4">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column3") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="cmdDel_Click"
                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this row? (cannot undo)');"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
<br />

<asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save Grid to Table" Style="margin-left:30px" OnClick="cmdSave_Click"/>
```

And the code looks like:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CreateTable();
            AddRow();
            LoadGrid();
            ViewState["MyTable"] = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["MyTable"];
        }
    }

    void CreateTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns[0].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dt.Columns[0].AutoIncrementStep = 1;
        dt.Columns[0].AutoIncrement = true;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
    }

    void AddRow()
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = "";
        dr["Column2"] = "";
        dr["Column3"] = "";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
       // Gridview1.Columns.Clear();
        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
        AddRow();
        LoadGrid();
    }

    void SaveData()
    {
        // move grid changes back to table
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in Gridview1.Rows)
        {
            //extract the TextBox values
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[gvRow.RowIndex];
            dr["Column1"] = ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
            dr["Column2"] = ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
            dr["Column3"] = ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("TextBox3")).Text;
        }
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }

    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
    }

    protected void cmdDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmdDel = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)cmdDel.Parent.Parent;

        dt.Rows[gvRow.RowIndex].Delete();
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

Of course the save button in real use would be "submit" and move on to the next web page, or whatever task the user is working on.

And I assume this is just for learning, since a table just sitting in memory has next to zero use. I would assume that the table would be from a database, else this setup not all that much use.

Comment: I'm uploading a gif to explain my problem more clearly.                                                          https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMDsh.gif

Comment: Do you plan to eventually use a database, or is just creating the table fine for this example? I will edit my post - but I am thinking it might be better to make this simple grid edit idea work against a datbase. The code is near identical in both cases, but if you are and have a database setup (say sql server), then I'll post a working example. But, if you just want a working table example - then I can do that. Also, for your images? You can put the image in your paste buffer, and while edition your post a ctrl-v to past the screen cap should work (no need for example linked images).

Comment: see my edit  and changed post. I show how this should work.

Comment: Yes, I will eventually use a database. but it will be like this: The user will add as many rows as he wants. then it will fill these lines. and all the rows that will save to the database.When he wants to delete a row, only the row will be deleted. Information in other rows will not be reset.

Comment: I'll try your codes and let you know the result. Thanks.

Comment: The codes are working fine but I have a new problem. For example, the user added 5 rows and did not add data to any of them. If we think that it starts adding data after adding the rows, after removing any row, the data in all rows is lost. I've updated the post and added the issue in gif format to the end.

Comment: Yes, but then you should be able to grasp the soluion. Just add SaveData() to the first line of the delete button code. Remember, we add rows, delete rows from the table, and THEN send the table to the grid. But edits in the grid don't move back to table unless we tell the code to move grid rows back to table rows. I mean, as I stated, the save data button right now only sends grid values back to table. The code in real use would most likely be a "ok I am done" or "submit" or whatever. The user thus can edit, add or delete rows.

Comment: In real use, the save data button probably would be called "submit" or "we are done - continue". And you don't need a loop to send the table back to the database - you can use  ONE update command to send all changes back to database.. (and if we are using a database table, then of course dump the code to create the table - use the actual database one. But yes, the above is "air code" just typed out by me. You should have been able to grasp that the delete code button needs as first line to call Savedata, and thus values will not disappear. So yes, I missed adding the SaveData in delete code

Comment: Oh Yes i understood. 
Sorry for not understanding the solution. I'm still new to coding.

Comment: Ok then, try adding SaveData() as first line of the delete button code - try that.

Comment: Yes, my problem is completely solved. Thanks for everything.